# Is it advisable to have Bluetooth-enabled devices for infants less than 2 years old?

Tags: technology, radiation

I have a Bluetooth-enabled health monitor watch. My concern is having such devices for infants who are less than 2 years old. Does it affect them health-wise??

Comment: I don't think the long term safety of these things are known yet, not enough to give recommendations.

Comment: Thank you Doctor whom .., do you think approaching FDA will give an answer on this ??

Comment: @goofyui This is basically the "Is EMR harmful" question, and nobody knows a firm answer to that, including the FDA. There is no convincing evidence that EMR at levels emitted by wireless devices is harmful, but there are credible doubters. Regardless, everyone is bathed in EMR from the day they're conceived in the womb until the day they die and short of living in an underground bunker, there's nothing you can do about that. More prior research on your part would tell you this.

Comment: Thank you Carey,  a long while ago.. i read an article about .impacts due to mobile phone calls ... or holding the phone close to your ears .. anyways.. all these questions will not have a definite answer.. thanks for clarifying ..

Comment: I really wish to have an answer which helps to stop the baby in the hot car incidents.. i wish to have a bluetooth enabled device tagged to the infants and have an app to notify the parents ..

Comment: @CareyGregory surely, you can't believe that "everyone is bathed in EMR from the day they're conceived in the womb"... If you walk around a house with a metering machine, there are extreme variations from the vicinity of some devices to a few meters away from it... meters are available online for under $100

Comment: @MicroMachine Recommend you read some basics of astronomy.

Comment: @CareyGregory I recommend [you purchase an electromagnetic field tester](https://imgur.com/3fZrgKz), and stop comparing devices whose long term effects have never been tested and that people wear or put against their bodies 24/7 to astral objects emitting radiation which humans have lived with for millions of years...

Comment: @MicroMachine Sounds like a fascinating debate but not for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no evidence that EMR in the dosages present in everyday activities can have any pernicious effect on human health. Nor is there a sound logical contention to back up such claim.

So, yes, feel free to use bluetooth, wifi, radio, etc. near your child. Even without them, there is a lot of EMR running amok around you, so there's not much you can actually do in that regard.

Comment: Its not about my child. I went on working on a product and then put that on hold. Product has to be approved by FDA or any Agencies who cares about Health & Safety. Question is related to commercial purpose of developing a product

Comment: I use "you" in an impersonal sense here; I don't literally mean "you", I mean people in general.

Comment: I agree with you Oligomath. But,  When a product is developed with a commercial intention, it has to go through approval from Health & Safety. I am trying to have more details before we get the product in the development phase.

Comment: I see your intention. If your concern is that the FDA will block the item in question on the account of health issue caused by bluetooth, I'd say that you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you Oligomath. However, i put that product development on hold.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Comment: As others have pointed out, current research says both yes and no on this topic. Of course if EMR is proven to be harmful without a doubt in the next few years, this will have a lot of impact on the world of tech. I personally stopped using some devices and some symptoms stopped right away. Cannot say more.